# Solving the Travelling Salesman Problem

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've been trying to find some kind of mathematical computer software to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem. The Excel Solver is able to do it, but I've noticed there is a built-in function in *Mathematica*:

> TravelingSalesman[g] finds an optimal traveling salesman tour in graph g.

I've been given a matrix which represents the costs of traveling between six cities. I could start typing them in to the `Graph` function and then use the `TravelingSalesman` function to solve it. But I'm too lazy for such work. Is there a way to type in the matrix, convert it to some kind of graph, and then apply the `TravelingSalesman` function directly to the graph?

Hope you understand my question! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://www.flinders.edu.au/science_engineering/csem/research/programs/flinders-hamiltonian-cycle-project/ which includes a link to the snakes and ladders web page for testing some solutions.  
FWIW the heuristics they have developed are supposedly orders of magnitude faster than the what Mathematica can do.

Comment: You might get decent results from FindShortestTour[...,DistanceFunction->...]

Comment: I found even better solution and updated the answer.

Comment: See the latest solution method by hand with zero or negligible error: P vs NP: Solutions of the Traveling Salesman Problem by A. A.Frempong At http://vixra.org/abs/1505.0167

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**True traveling salesman problem**

`FindShortestTour` is the function you are looking for. This defines a sparse distance matrix among six points and finds the shortest tour:

```
d = SparseArray[{{1, 2} -> 1, {2, 1} -> 1, {6, 1} -> 1, {6, 2} -> 
     1, {5, 1} -> 1, {1, 5} -> 1, {2, 6} -> 1, {2, 3} -> 10, {3, 2} ->
      10, {3, 5} -> 1, {5, 3} -> 1, {3, 4} -> 1, {4, 3} -> 
     1, {4, 5} -> 15, {4, 1} -> 1, {5, 4} -> 15, {5, 2} -> 
     1, {1, 4} -> 1, {2, 5} -> 1, {1, 6} -> 1}, {6, 6}, Infinity];


{len, tour} = FindShortestTour[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, DistanceFunction -> (d[[#1, #2]] &)]
```

> {6, {1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6}}

This plots the shortest tour in red, and the distance on each edge:

```
HighlightGraph[
  WeightedAdjacencyGraph[d, GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"], 
  Style[UndirectedEdge[#1, #2], Thickness[.01], Red] & @@@ Partition[tour, 2, 1, 1]]
```

[image]

**Some other experiments with graphs**

Another interesting thing to look at is ([**FindPostmanTour function**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bh05gfvekxzyr-cn85r0)), but below method is also interesting. Sample matrix of  cost quantities (distances, times, expenses, etc.) between the cities:

```
m = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]; (m[[#, #]] = Infinity) & /@ Range[10]; m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Matrix should be of course symmetric, but DirectedEdges -> False below takes care of it. A default embedding would of course give a complete graph:

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[m, DirectedEdges -> False, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

While weighted embedding results in edges length reflecting upon distances:

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[m, DirectedEdges -> False, GraphLayout ->   
{"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Now get vertex coordinates, find shortest tour:

```
p = GraphEmbedding[g]
```

> {{1.28207, 1.43548}, {0.63296, 0.7209}, {1.01456, 0.812491}, 
>       {1.27993,0.}, {1.16843, 1.46467}, {0.0713373, 1.23935}, 
>       {1.29842, 1.4204}, {0., 1.22425}, {0.167924, 0.587497}, {0.643434, 1.17666}}

```
st = FindShortestTour[p]
```

> {5.02343, {1, 5, 10, 6, 8, 9, 2, 4, 3, 7}}

```
Show[g, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[p[[Last[st]]]]}]]
```

[image]

**Just shortest path (not through all cities)**

Lets choose a test weighted matrix:

```
m = {{\[Infinity], 1, 7, \[Infinity]}, {1, \[Infinity], 2, 5}, {7, 
    2, \[Infinity], 1}, {\[Infinity], 5, 1, \[Infinity]}};
m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Infinity means no edge between vertices. This builds the graph:

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[m, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork"]
```

[image]

Find shortest path between vertices 1 and 4 and visualize:

```
sp = FindShortestPath[g, 1, 4]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

```
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[sp]]
```

[image]

which is obviously correct.

**Known positions of the cities**

If you know locations or names of the cities, then [**take a look at this**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0c0pqeanjudsj-b6jyvb). A short example traveling through the centro-ids of countries in Europe:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], Gray, CountryData[#, "Polygon"] & /@ 
CountryData["Europe"], Thick, Red, Line[#[[Last[FindShortestTour[#]]]] &
[Reverse[CountryData[#, "CenterCoordinates"]] & /@ CountryData["Europe"]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: As always, thorough and outstanding answer.

Comment: I note that randomly drawing distances between cities, as you do with the random matrix, will quite probably lead to positions of cities that are inconsistent with the 2D or 3D space they supposedly live in. You better start with random positions and derive distances from that.

Comment: Something like `Outer[EuclideanDistance, #, #, 1]&[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]] /.  0. -> \[Infinity]` should do.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Found a better solution. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 8):

As Vitaliy shows, you can probably use `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`.  Of course, it would be much easier to answer the question correctly, if you included an example.  Also, it's really not hard to find such functions.  Near the bottom of the help for the `Graph` command, you'll find pointers to related functions.  In this case, there's a pointer to the `AdjacencyGraph` command:

[image]

Then, from that page, you'll find a pointer to the `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` command.  Judging from your two questions, I'd say that understanding how to navigate the documentation would be very fruitful.  Even "lazy" folks can do it!:)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'll try to use even more time in the Documentation Center before asking "lazy" questions! ;)

Comment: @MarcoDalFarra Great! Sometimes, it's just a matter of learning how to use that type of resource.