# I can't understand FindShortestTour

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry

I can't understand the function `FindShortestTour` because of the result:

```
FindShortestTour[{{0, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}, {10, 1}}]
```

> {20, {1, 2, 4, 3}}

and I think that the result should be:

> {10, {1, 3, 2, 4}}

or

> {10, {4, 2, 3, 1}}

Comment: A tour goes back to the starting point. Your proposed tours, if they do so as well, have length 20 and thus are no shorter than the one found by `FoundShortestTour`. That is, the distance is calculated as `Total[Norm /@ (pts[[tour]] - pts[[RotateLeft[tour]]])]` (or something equivalent to that), where `pts` is the list of points and `tour` is the result given by `FindShortestTour`. Another way to see this is to specify `Method -> "AllTours"` or `Method -> "IntegerLinearProgramming"`, both of which find guaranteed optimal tours. The result won't change.

Comment: @OleksandrR. should write this as an answer since it directly addresses the OPs question of what it means to be a "shortest tour".

Comment: @bill-s I understand Oleksandr R.  A tour must come back (in the last "movement") to the starting point. In the first solution, The tour is START Visiting 1, Visit2, Visit,4,visit 3, and come back to Visit 1. FINISH.

Comment: `FindShortestTour[{{0, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}, {10, 1}}, 1, 4]` yields `{10, {1, 3, 2, 4}}`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. - the [`documentation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html)  under `Possible Issues` states" `Use PerformanceGoal->"Quality" to find an optimal result` (although `PerformanceGoal` is not documented under `Details and Options`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *tour* must return to the starting point; i.e. it is a cycle. Your proposed tours with lengths of 10 are not, and therefore could not have been found by `FindShortestTour`. Calculating the length explicitly shows that all three (the tour found by `FindShortestTour` and your proposed tours, when interpreted as returning to the beginning) have a length of 20, which is the minimum possible in this example:

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}, {10, 1}};
{len, tour} = FindShortestTour[pts];

ClearAll[tourEdgeLengths, tourLength];
tourEdgeLengths[pts_, tour_] := Norm /@ (pts[[tour]] - pts[[RotateLeft[tour]]]);
tourLength[pts_, tour_] := Total@tourEdgeLengths[pts, tour];

tourLength[pts, tour] (* FindShortestTour result is {1, 2, 4, 3} *)
(* -> 20 *)

tourLength[pts, {1, 3, 2, 4}]
(* -> 20 *)

tourLength[pts, {4, 2, 3, 1}]
(* -> 20 *)
```

Indeed, the methods `"AllTours"` and `"IntegerLinearProgramming"` are guaranteed to find the shortest tour, and these produce the same result as the default method.

The result obtained from `FindShortestTour` is a good example of the fact that, when seeking a traversal that is not a tour, in general one can *not* simply find the shortest cycle and then delete its longest edge to get the optimum solution. This would be the case for your tour `{1, 3, 2, 4}`:

```
tourEdgeLengths[pts, {1, 3, 2, 4}]
(* -> {2, 3, 5, 10} *)
```

i.e., deleting the last edge (4$\rightarrow$1, length 10) produces the shortest Hamiltonian path. But, when considering the equally good tour `{1, 2, 4, 3}`,

```
tourEdgeLengths[pts, {1, 2, 4, 3}]
(* -> {5, 5, 8, 2} *)
```

we see that deleting the edge 4$\rightarrow$3 (length 8) leaves us with a non-optimal, length-12 traversal.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that result (Linux, 64 bit). Indeed, a good example that shows how bad some (most) outputs of FindShortestTour are. I've made a few posts regarding the add-on package [JVMTools](http://www.jvmtools.net/jt.html) already, for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26742/findshortesttour-for-charity-or-how-can-i-optimize-meal-delivery-with-findshor/26761#26761), so I'll just keep it with that link. JVMTools uses industrial-strength algorithms that produce optimal solutions for a few hundred nodes in a few seconds, and solutions that are only 1 - 2% above optimal for a few thousand nodes. All algorithms use concurrency to submit competing strategies and initial nodes (and then returns either all solutions or only the best, based on the user's choice), and also uses ant-colony / multi-agent optimization algorithms for outstanding quality and speed results.

Disclosure: I am the owner of Lauschke Consulting, which is the business that sells JVMTools commercially.

Comment: Can you please edit the second sentence where you claim that this is a good example of bad `FindShortestTour` input?

Comment: @Jacob: I think there is no need to edit, my sentence is correct. It is a good example that shows how bad  FindShortestTour outputs can be. I never made a claim about FindShortestTour inputs (as that comes from the user).

Comment: Ah yes, I should have said output. But please see the comment and answer by OleksandrR and consider the difference between finding a minimum length tour (Hamiltonian cycle) and a minimum length Hamiltonian path.

Comment: To be fair, I have asked a [question on the meta site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1050/4330) featuring this answer as a major example.

Answer (score 5):

`FindShortestTour` is a complex function with multiple operation levels.

First of all there are two steps for `FindShortestTour`:

1. Tour generation
2. Tour improvement

`FindShortestTour` implements several tour generation methods. 
Space-filling curves is one for instance, another one is *CCA* (convex hull, cheapest insertion, angle selection).

All the methods for tour generation and tour improvement are not applied to your example, since there are not enough points. In your case `FindShortestPath` is clever enough and will switch to `Minimize`, implementing an elaborate *Integer Linear Programming* approach. (**Caution!** That _Mathematica) is using `[N]Minimize` internally might not be true at all. Let's suppose it does.)

Let's try to mimic what *Mathematica* is doing under the hood, when switching to `Minimize`.

- set up a variable which holds 1 or 0 if an edge from one point $i$ to another point $j$ is in the optimal tour
- minimize the total cost of the tour defined by the 1s

The problem with this approach is that the solution will be a collection of cycles.

Here the *tour improvement* step comes into play.

The first cycles after the first call to `Minimize` are killed. This is repeated as long as there is a cycle which involves all n points. Perfectly if this last cycle is a *Hamilton cycle* and the optimal tour (please see OleksandrR's answer).

The whole iterative process seems to be rather costly and it is indeed. That's why FindShortestTour switches to it only if the amount of points is smaller than a threshold.

Surprisingly it terminates quickly if the threshold is low enough.

The solution to your problem is `{1, 3, 2, 4}` and `{1, 2, 4, 3}` as well. They're all straight lines and since Euclid we know that lines are the shortest connections :).
And as OleksandR already pointed out, that a tour is only a tour if you return to the starting point that's why the length is 20.

Comment: Does `FindShortestTour` really call `Minimize` (internally)? I did not find this in the docs, nor in `Information[FindShortestTour]` after removing the attribute `ReadProtected`, nor in `Trace[FindShortestTour[{{0, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}, {10, 1}}], 
 TraceInternal -> True]`. I do not think there will be a tour improvement step after the linear programming, as I think the linear programming will yield an optimal solution directly. There are probably relaxed linear programs which return some cycles, but there also equivalent formulations of TSP using LP. I suppose Mathematica just uses that.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom hmmm. maybe that shot was careless. I suppose yes, if Mma switches to an ILP approach...and what function is better suited for that than [N]Minimize. Well I guess your are right concerning those points that there will be no improvement step, but if there are more points I suppose there will be tour improvement involved, if they are using Minimize for that. The algorithm I described is based on iteratively minimizing the result until you get your hamilton and tsp.