# Forcing optimal solution for FindShortestTour

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization, traversal

I use `FindShortestTour` as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15985/solving-the-travelling-salesman-problem) and it works nicely for a small number of cities. However when I try this with as little as 16 cities, the given tour isn't optimal anymore. I've tried using different `Methods` but none of them gave me the optimal tour (solutions within a 5% to 400% range of the optimal solution).

How can I force Mathematica to give me the optimal solution?

**Edit**:

This is my code (pretty much copy-paste from the link above as I'm very new to Mathematica)

```
dim = 16;
max = 100;

(* create symmetric matrix with random integers *)
d = RandomInteger[max, {dim, dim}];
d = Table[If[i > j, d[[i, j]], d[[j, i]]], {i, 1, Length[d[[1]]]}, {j, 1,Length[d[[1]]]}];
(d[[#, #]] = Infinity) & /@ Range[dim];
d // Grid

(* find tour *)
{len, tour} = FindShortestTour[Range[dim], DistanceFunction -> (d[[#1, #2]] &), 
  Method -> "TwoOpt"]

(* display tour *)
HighlightGraph[ WeightedAdjacencyGraph[d, DirectedEdges -> False, 
  GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"], 
 Style[UndirectedEdge[#1, #2], Thickness[.01], Red] & @@@ Partition[tour, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: "IntegerLinearProgramming" doesn't give you the shortest?

Comment: @Rojo It's strangely enough one of the worst, it gave me `888` as distance whereas the optimal was `198`. The best for this specific layout was `TwoOpt` giving me a solution of `205` but none of them ever seem to give me an optimal solution. (which I need to compare my algorithm against)

Comment: @Aerus Perhaps you should post you code?

Comment: @Lou updated with code

Comment: The fact that "IntegerLinearProgramming" fails in such spectacular fashion seems to indicate the second problem today that has shown up in certain integer programming library code. I guess I need to file some reports.

Comment: Okay, this one at least will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: The method "TwoOpt" is a local search combinatorial heuristic, it is fast but there is no guarantee of optimality of the solution. You can google "TSP 2-opt" for more info. For such methods the function should probably be renamed `FindDecentlyShortTour` (!)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This example now fails with a typo in the internal code.  I filed a report.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry about that. Will fix.

Answer (score 4):

[Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) [has confirmed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/forcing-optimal-solution-for-findshortesttour/40288#comment107317_34958) that this is a problem with the integer linear programming code. Moreover, a bug report has been filed and the problem [will be addressed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/forcing-optimal-solution-for-findshortesttour/40288#comment107325_34958) in a future version.