# FindShortestTour finds very long tour

Tags: programming

The documentation claims FindShortestTour works extremely well for hundreds or thousands of cities. I show an example set of 5 cities where it does an abominable job. I also show a couple of absurd changes that fix the problem. Does anyone have more experience with this?

```
placeData = {{1.3, 31.8}, {1.5, 32.}, {1.5, 32.}, {1.3, 31.8}, {1.3, 31.8}};
Outer[EuclideanDistance, placeData, placeData, 1] // TableForm

0.      0.282843    0.282843    0.  0.  
0.282843    0.      0.      0.282843    0.282843  
0.282843    0.      0.      0.282843    0.282843  
0.      0.282843    0.282843    0.  0.  
0.      0.282843    0.282843    0.  0.
```

Note from the matrix above that one quirk of the data is that there are only 2 different positions. The best route is {2,3,1,4,5}, which traverses the distance between the two positions only once.
The tour returned by FindShortestTour makes the traversal 3 times, which is shockingly far from optimal (3 times as bad as the best!):

```
tourLength[cities_] := Total[(EuclideanDistance @@ #) & /@ Partition[cities, 2, 1]]
FindShortestTour[placeData, 2, 5]
tourLength[Part[placeData, Last@%]]
tourLength[Part[placeData, {2, 3, 1, 4, 5}]]

{0.848528, {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}}  
0.848528  
0.282843
```

Just by shifting the data by 1 unit, FindShortestTour works properly:

```
Plus[{0,-1},#]&/@placeData
FindShortestTour[%,2,5]

{{1.3,30.8},{1.5,31.},{1.5,31.},{1.3,30.8},{1.3,30.8}}  
{0.282843,{2,3,1,4,5}}
```

Adding(!) another (duplicate!) city also fixes the problem, surprisingly:

```
placeData
FindShortestTour[%,2,5]
Append[%%,Last@%%]
FindShortestTour[%,2,5]

{{1.3,31.8},{1.5,32.},{1.5,32.},{1.3,31.8},{1.3,31.8}}  
{0.848528,{2,1,3,4,5}}  
{{1.3,31.8},{1.5,32.},{1.5,32.},{1.3,31.8},{1.3,31.8},{1.3,31.8}}  
{0.282843,{2,3,6,4,1,5}}
```

Advice, anyone? Since no errors or messages are thrown, the only way I can think of to detect this problem is to write another version of FindShortestTour to check it against. I'd like to avoid that. ;-)

I know about [this SE report](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/forcing-optimal-solution-for-findshortesttour), but that was 4 years ago. I am currently running version 11.1.0 on MacOS 10.13.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose `exact` data

```
placeData = {{1.3, 31.8}, {1.5, 32.}, {1.5, 32.}, {1.3, 31.8}, {1.3,31.8}} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
```

the shortest tour evluates as expected

```
FindShortestTour[placeData, 2, 5] // N
(*{0.282843, {2., 3., 1., 4., 5.}}*)
```

Comment: So, @Ulrich, you have added a third twiddle that gets FindShortestTour to suddenly behave. Thanks. But are you suggesting that this might always be a fix? Or is it just another quirky alteration that helps the case of this one dataset?

Comment: @Carib John  When I first read your question I thought about the scaling of your data. If you normalize the data everything seems to work: `m = Mean[data];\[Sigma] = StandardDeviation[data];FindShortestTour[
 Map[{(#[[1]] - m[[1]])/\[Sigma] [[1]], (#[[2]] - 
     m[[2]])/\[Sigma] [[2]]} &, data], 2, 5](*{2.58199, {2, 3, 1, 4, 5}}*)`