# Problem with FindShortestTour function

Tags: functions, matrix, graphs-and-networks

I'm new to Mathematica but I've read some documentation and guides and, unfortunately, haven't found a solution.

There's the following matrix in the task:

[image]

And I have to solve this TSP problem specifically with the help of `FindShortestTour` function. Not `FindShortestPath` or sth else.

I have tried several variants, but if I do something like this:`FindShortestTour[{{\[Infinity], 10, 20, 15}, {30, \[Infinity], 25, 
   20}, {18, 22, \[Infinity], 24}, {10, 15, 20, \[Infinity]}}]` I get a mistake: `The distance function EuclideanDistance does not give a numerical result when applied to two points.` I guess that's because of Infinity symbols inside a matrix.

Comment: It is said, that "Infinity means no edge between vertices."
TSP - travelling salesman problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15985/7167).  See if one of those answers helps you out.

Comment: I tried to solve it like in th link you provided, but the solution wasn't right.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `∞` by `0`:

```
A = {{∞, 10, 20, 15}, {30, ∞, 25, 20}, {18, 22, ∞, 24}, {10, 15, 20, ∞}} ;
FindShortestTour[A/. ∞ -> 0]
```

Actually, a distance matrix in which a vertex has infinite distance does not make sense.

> {5 Sqrt[14] + 5 Sqrt[42] + 3 Sqrt[141] + Sqrt[949], {1, 4, 2, 3, 1}}

Comment: It is asid, that "Infinity means no edge between vertices".
And yeah, I tried to replace it with 0, but the result is still wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.  I've cut and pasted the code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15986/7167) so go upvote that instead.

```
d = SparseArray[{{1, 2} -> 10, {1, 3} -> 20, {1, 4} -> 15, {2, 1} -> 
     30, {2, 3} -> 25, {2, 4} -> 20, {3, 1} -> 18, {3, 2} -> 
     22, {3, 4} -> 24, {4, 1} -> 10, {4, 2} -> 15, {4, 3} -> 20}, {4, 
    4}, Infinity];
{len, tour} = 
 FindShortestTour[{1, 2, 3, 4}, DistanceFunction -> (d[[#1, #2]] &)]
HighlightGraph[
 WeightedAdjacencyGraph[d, GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"], 
 Style[DirectedEdge[#1, #2], Thickness[.01], Red] & @@@ 
  Partition[tour, 2, 1, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: THAT'S IT! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do note that the C&P solution complains because your matrix is not symmetric.  Also, I don't get the fancy highlighted path.  I don't know enough about the graph functions to know why this is the case.  Caveat Emptor.

Comment: Shamelessly seeking a hat, can you accept this answer **without** voting it up?